# How did you convert primary alcohol using HCl (with ZnCl2)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

I kinda feel weird for this type of question. When primary OH (alcohol) is converted with HCl (with ZnCl2), how did the free Cl-ion come from? If, it is came from HCl, since when we get rid of the H from HCl?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Though the [Lucas' reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_reagent) is a solution of *concentrated* $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{ZnCl2}$, it still is an aqueous solution containing $\ce{Cl^-}$, because

- as a strong acid, practically all $\ce{HCl}$ in the aqueous phase dissociated *
- $\ce{ZnCl2}$ is well water soluble

* One can purchase solutions of HCl in organic solvents which (depending of the solvent) may prohibit the dissociation.  An example of such a "dry solution"  is $\ce{HCl}$ in diethyl ether ([entry at Sigma](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sigald/455180)).